# every open set is the disjoint union of open intervals (proof verification)

Tags: elementary-set-theory

[image]

This is from Royden. I don't understand the red line. For example, if $\mathcal{O}$ is $(0,1)$, $a_x$ and $b_x$ should be at least $0$ and $1$, respectively not to be included in $\mathcal{O}$. Then, how can $(I_x)_{x \in \mathcal{O}}$ be disjoint?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Seems like that it should be "either $I_x \cap I_y = \varnothing$ or $I_x = I_y$".